# A control/script for image manipulation

Tags: asp.net

I have a Web application (ASP.NET WebForms) . I want it to be able to display an image and perform the following manipulations with it:

- To Zoom In / Zoom Out the image. There must be a scrolling when the image is zoomed in
- To Rotate (Flip) the image on 90 degrees

In can use only HTML+JavaScript for this task. I CANNOT use Java applets, Flash or Silverlight
Is there a control/JavaScript/anything  that provides this functionality? I have already looked at DevExpress for this and found nothing

Comment: good comment! i also think you should work on that...

Answer (score 0):

Look at raphael and jquery. For jquery there are some plugins you can use.

Raphael:

http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html

jquery:

http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/zoom

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: The http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html works with VECTOR format SVG. This is not suitable for me: I need to operate with GIF,JPEG,PNG.

The http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ performs ROTTAION only; and the http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/zoom performs ZOOM only. But I need BOTH in the same control. 
Maybe you may tell me more controls?

Comment: The http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html works with VECTOR format SVG. This is not suitable for me: I need to operate with GIF,JPEG,PNG.

The http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ performs ROTTAION only; and the http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/zoom performs ZOOM only. But I need BOTH in the same control. 
Maybe you may tell me more controls?

Comment: The jquery plugins are not mutually exclusive. You can do $('#image').rotate(90) and then also $('#image').fancyzoom(). Add it to a function and try it out.